# Clj-sentiment dependency

Tags: github, clojure, leiningen

What dependency should be used for `clj-sentiment`? I have neither found it on the github https://github.com/AndreasKostler/clj-sentiment nor have I been able to locate it within clojars.

The reason I am using this library is to implement the algorithm within https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/clojure/7GMuLVvToCE/WmT04KY0_yYJ where the `create-cluster` function calls to the library for the function `get-feature-vec`. I searched through all of the branches of this github library for the function `get-feature-vec` to exclude the need for the dependency. However the search returned empty.

Comment: Isn't the information under project.clj sufficient for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do a git checkout of github project, `lein install` inside project dir and use library name and version from project.clj

```
[clj-sentiment "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"]
```